Writing CSV in TwinCAT 3 is unintentionally skipping rows and unsure why
I am using a PLC from Beckhoff and working in TwinCat3.
I have been trying to implement logic to write trial data from a lab test to a csv upon the test's completion. Currently, the way I'm attempting to do this is by first storing the data in memory (in the variable aTrialDataBuffer, shown below), and then once the test completes, writing that data to disk in a .csv.
My current problem is that the test data is stored in the memory buffer perfectly fine, without any skipped iterations, but when reviewing the .csv afterwards, only about every 4-6 rows ends up getting logged. I understand there are some subtleties with getting FB_FileOpen, FB_FileClose, and FB_FilePuts to work properly, and have been following guides on a few previously asked questions on SO:
How do I save data from my PLC in Excel or CSV format in TwinCAT?
TwinCAT 3: Write to File
However, for the life of me I haven't been able to figure out why this row skipping is occurring. I put my program into debug mode as well, and noted that FB_FilePuts appears to be called without skipping any iterations (by manually inspecting the string argument). I suspect I am still missing a small subtlety in how to properly use the bExecute flag, but haven't been able to resolve the issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Code is down below.
FUNCTION_BLOCK CalibrationBlockLogger
VAR_INPUT
    sFileName : STRING; 
END_VAR
VAR_OUTPUT
    bBusy : BOOL := FALSE; 
    bError : BOOL := FALSE; 
END_VAR
VAR CONSTANT
    nMaxBufferSize : UDINT := 6000000;
END_VAR
VAR
    cDefaultHeader : T_MaxString := 'TimeLow, TimeHigh, EncoderDegrees, CommandVoltage, CommandTorque, GripForce, GripThreshold, SequenceState, CurrentTestIndex, TestIsLive $n'; 
    sDefaultDirectory : T_MaxString := 'C:\Users\njanne\Documents\DDTestLogs\'; 
    bWriteToDisk : BOOL := FALSE; 
    eFileWriteState : (IDLE, OPEN_FILE, WAIT_FOR_OPEN, WRITE_TO_FILE, WAIT_FOR_WRITE, CLOSE_FILE, WAIT_FOR_CLOSE, ERROR); 
    fbFileOpen : FB_FileOpen; 
    fbFilePuts : FB_FilePuts; 
    fbFileClose : FB_FileClose; 
    fbFormatString : FB_FormatString2; 
    nFileHandle : UINT; 
    bHeaderWriteComplete : BOOL := FALSE; 
    nWriteIndex : UDINT := 0; 
    
    // For formatting data into a string. 
    sDataFormatStr : STRING := '%d, %d, %f, %f, %f, %f, %f, %s, %d, %d $n'; 
    sTempString : STRING(600); 
    
    aTrialDataBuffer : ARRAY[0..nMaxBufferSize] OF ST_CalibTrialStep; 
    nStepsSoFar : UDINT := 0; // Current number of steps in the database. 
    
END_VAR
--------------------------------------
IF bWriteToDisk THEN // externally set to TRUE once the test is complete, and is set FALSE once the file closes in this state machine. 

    // If it's time to write to disk, we need to empty the buffer.
    CASE eFileWriteState OF 
        
        IDLE: 
            // Get everything ready. 
            nFileHandle := 0; 
            bBusy := TRUE; 
            eFileWriteState := OPEN_FILE; 
    
        OPEN_FILE: 
        
            // Opens a file for writing at the end of the file (append). 
            // If the file does not exist, a new file is created. 
            fbFileOpen(bExecute := FALSE); 
            fbFileOpen(
                bExecute        := TRUE, 
                sNetID          := '',
                sPathName       := CONCAT(sDefaultDirectory, sFilename), 
                nMode           := FOPEN_MODEAPPEND OR FOPEN_MODETEXT); 

            eFileWriteState := WAIT_FOR_OPEN; 

        WAIT_FOR_OPEN: 
            fbFileOpen(bExecute := FALSE); 
            IF fbFileOpen.bError THEN
                eFileWriteState := ERROR; 
            ELSIF NOT fbFileOpen.bBusy THEN
                nFileHandle := fbFileOpen.hFile; 
                eFileWriteState := WRITE_TO_FILE; 
            END_IF

        WRITE_TO_FILE: 
            // First check if we need to write the header. 
            IF NOT bHeaderWriteComplete THEN
                fbFilePuts(bExecute := FALSE); 
                fbFilePuts(
                    bExecute        := TRUE, 
                    sNetId          := '', 
                    hFile           := nFileHandle, 
                    sLine           := cDefaultHeader); 
                    
                eFileWriteState := WAIT_FOR_WRITE; 
                bHeaderWriteComplete := TRUE; 
            ELSE
                // If the header is already written, then we're going for data. 
                // We need to first format the string.      
                fbFormatString(
                    pFormatString := ADR(sDataFormatStr), 
                    arg1 := F_UDINT(aTrialDataBuffer[nWriteIndex].nTimestepLow), 
                    arg2 := F_UDINT(aTrialDataBuffer[nWriteIndex].nTimeStepHigh), 
                    arg3 := F_REAL(aTrialDataBuffer[nWriteIndex].rEncoderDegrees), 
                    arg4 := F_REAL(aTrialDataBuffer[nWriteIndex].rCommandVoltage), 
                    arg5 := F_REAL(aTrialDataBuffer[nWriteIndex].rCommandTorque), 
                    arg6 := F_REAL(aTrialDataBuffer[nWriteIndex].rGripForce),  
                    arg7 := F_REAL(aTrialDataBuffer[nWriteIndex].rCurrentGripThreshold), 
                    arg8 := F_STRING(aTrialDataBuffer[nWriteIndex].sSequenceStateString),
                    arg9 := F_INT(aTrialDataBuffer[nWriteIndex].nCurrentTestIndex), 
                    //arg10 := F_INT(aTrialDataBuffer[nWriteIndex].nTestIsLive), 
                    arg10 := F_UDINT(nWriteIndex), // TODO: DELETE
                    pDstString := ADR(sTempString), 
                    nDstSize := SIZEOF(sTempString)); 
                
                fbFilePuts(bExecute := FALSE); 
                fbFilePuts(
                    bExecute        := TRUE, 
                    sNetId          := '', 
                    hFile           := nFileHandle, 
                    sLine           := sTempString); 
                    
                // Update the next iteration if we need to write more. 
                nWriteIndex := nWriteIndex + 1; 
                eFileWriteState := WAIT_FOR_WRITE; 
            END_IF
            
        WAIT_FOR_WRITE: 
            fbFilePuts(bExecute := FALSE); 
            IF fbFilePuts.bError THEN
                eFileWriteState := ERROR; 
            ELSIF NOT fbFileClose.bBusy THEN
                // Success, data was written. 
                // Check if we need to write anything more. 
                IF nWriteIndex = nStepsSoFar THEN
                    eFileWriteState := CLOSE_FILE; 
                ELSE
                    eFileWriteState := WRITE_TO_FILE; // Go back to writer. 
                END_IF
            END_IF
            
        CLOSE_FILE: 
            fbFileClose(bExecute := FALSE); 
            fbFileClose(
                bExecute    := TRUE, 
                sNetId      := '', 
                hFile       := nFileHandle); 
                
            eFileWriteState := WAIT_FOR_CLOSE;
            
        WAIT_FOR_CLOSE: 
            fbFileClose(bExecute := FALSE); 
            IF fbFileClose.bError THEN 
                eFileWriteState := ERROR; 
                
            ELSIF NOT fbFileClose.bBusy THEN
                nFileHandle := 0; 
                eFileWriteState := IDLE; 
                
                // Also reset everything so that a new test can overwrite.  
                nStepsSoFar := 0; 
                nWriteIndex := 0; 
                bHeaderWriteComplete := FALSE; 
                bBusy := FALSE; 
                bWriteToDisk := FALSE; 
                
            END_IF
                
        ERROR: 
            // Error, clear the handle and go back to idle. 
            nFileHandle := 0; 
            eFileWriteState := IDLE; 
            bError := TRUE; 
    
    END_CASE

END_IF


FWIW, new data is added to aTrialDataBuffer and nStepsSoFar is incremented via a small method that is called during the test itself:
METHOD addStep : BOOL
VAR_INPUT
    stNewStep : ST_CalibTrialStep; // The incoming step to be added to memory
END_VAR
-------------------------
// We need to simply copy over all the fields into the new position. 
// And then, update the counter. 
MEMCPY(
    destAddr := ADR(aTrialDataBuffer[nStepsSoFar]), 
    srcAddr := ADR(stNewStep), 
    n := SIZEOF(ST_CalibTrialStep)); 
    
nStepsSoFar := nStepsSoFar + 1; 

I am also calling the function block that does the writing continuously in a parent program, to satisfy the update of the state machine.

I haven't worked with Beckoff, let alone FB_FilePuts, but the first things I'd check is: 1. Does the execution timeout? Maybe try setting a larger one ("DEFAULT_ADS_TIMEOUT is a global constant, set to 5 seconds"). 2. Does the bBusy flag get raised imediately upon the execution with Execute TRUE? If not, that would definitely skip some, though I don't know why it wouldn't be set. 3. Maybe try puting some delay bewteen line writes ¯\(ツ)/¯

You need to monitor the bBusy bit of fbFilePuts to know when writing is done and it's OK to proceed. I think maybe you used fbFileClose.bBusy by mistake in WAIT_FOR_WRITE?
Corrected code:
    WAIT_FOR_WRITE: 
        fbFilePuts(bExecute := FALSE); 
        IF fbFilePuts.bError THEN
            eFileWriteState := ERROR; 
        ELSIF NOT fbFilePuts.bBusy THEN
            //    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
            // Success, data was written. 
            // Check if we need to write anything more. 
            IF nWriteIndex = nStepsSoFar THEN
                eFileWriteState := CLOSE_FILE; 
            ELSE
                eFileWriteState := WRITE_TO_FILE; // Go back to writer. 
            END_IF
        END_IF 


You are right, I also missed that! It's easy to miss such things, especially without syntax highlighting :P

Man has a sharp eye, good catch :)
